# Multiple Files to a project in c++

Tags: c++, file

I have been writing code for a little while now and I recently found out how to create classes in different files and include them in main, along with more cpp files including the definitions of those classes. I was wondering when this is really needed, my code isnt normally that long. Should I use this now as a beginning when my code is only a few hundred lines or less or are the multiple files used with alot more code. In cases like this with such a short code I could probably find it easier just to stick to the main cpp. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise for the sake of organization that you should create a new set of files - .h and .cpp - for each new functionality you want to add.  That doesn't mean create a new file for ever *class* you want to have.  As an example, you can define a `Sound` class and a `SoundManager` class in the same header if you want.  It's easier to find and edit a faulty piece of code when it isn't all jumbled up with other code in a catch-all file.

When you get to multi-thousand or even multi-million line projects (which I'm sure you will sooner or later), you will obviously be in for a world of pain if you shove it all into one file.  Like [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962761/3151642) said, it's better learn it correctly the first time than to relearn it correctly the second time.

Answer (score 2):

Bad habits are easy to learn and hard to unlearn. Why not do it the right way from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different parts of your code in different files, then you can open each file in a new editor window and view them side by side instead of having to jump up and down in the same file

Yeah, I know that some editors have a "split window" mode, but those don't play nicely with multiple monitors, etc, etc